# Can't detect jQuery click on vimeo iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, click, vimeo

Simple Vimeo iframe click does not work:

```
$('iframe').click(function(){
    alert('ok');
});
```

I've also tried:

```
$('body').click(..
$(document).on('click','iframe',..
```

But when user clicks video while hovering it, nothing works, it just plays the video.

Comment: Perhaps the [Vimeo JavaScript API](http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api) will meet your needs

Comment: yeah that way is working like a charm but i still wonder is there an alternate way to detect click without using api @DACrosby

Comment: @BarlasApaydin It seems like you're out of luck. Since the iframe is on a different domain name than your own, you basically can't without the API to my knowledge. [Here's me trying](http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/XWybM/). [Here's an SO post that explains it pretty well](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3083131/1265817).

Answer (score 7):

if you include the query parameter `api=1` in your embed code, you can access events, including those events triggered when the user clicks the video in the iframe (play,pause). You'll also probably want to include their `froogaloop.js` file to more easily access these events.

```
<iframe id="player1" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/27855315?api=1&player_id=player1" width="400" height="225"></iframe>
```

- http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api
- http://jsfiddle.net/bdougherty/HfwWY/light
- https://github.com/vimeo/player-api/tree/master/javascript

Comment: +1 from me for good answer but can't you show an alternative and easier way to just sens click on iframe with jsFiddle? Than i'll give you the bounty (:

Comment: anyways, it seems we don't have another way for detecting lick without api, bounty is yours.

Answer (score 1):

It is a third party domian in the iframe, you can not do it because of [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$('iframe').contents()
           .find('[src*="vimeo.com"]')
           .click(
               function(){
                  alert('foo');
               }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot track clicks in cross-domain iframes due to same origin policy, as epascarello has previously said.

You could set up a "thumbnail" that the user clicks, which would pull up that popup and then subsequently replace the thumbnail with the actual video. Just embed the video you want, but keep it as a hidden div, then use `.show()` when you want it to start playing.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975987/swap-image-with-embedded-vimeo-video-when-image-is-clicked)

Comment: thanks for return but you can play better than this mate, where is working jsFiddle?

Comment: we can use vimeo api for detecting it.

Answer (score -1):

I found that before I could get anything inside the iframe to be found I needed to determine if the iframe was loaded. Then if the iframe gets loaded after page load or reloaded later in the process, your click function works.

```
jQuery('#iframe').load(function() {
   jQuery('#iframe').contents().find('#play-button').click(function () {
        // do your stuff
    });
}
```

** this may or may not work cross-domain, but determining if the iframe loaded can be used as a hackish method of determining if something has happened in the iframe. If you created a "play" button on your domain on top of the iframe it could be used to load the iframe via a click function after page load and then your load function could contain your slideshow pause.